# Android wrap_content not work - It's too big

Tags: android, drawable

I often work with `wrap_content`. And it works properly.

But recently something went wrong - if I do not give the size of the image, it looks a lot bigger than it really is.

Maybe it's because I had to work with Android Studio.
I do not know.

**Edit:**

image.png size is 160px x 160px

```
<ImageView
          android:layout_width="160px"
          android:layout_height="160px"
          android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

That's how everything looks fine.

```
<ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

But now that picture looks too big.

I know that the right way is to use in `wrap_content`, but because this issue I can't.

Comment: are you asking something? if so please supply relevant data like code. thanks

Comment: where is your question ?

Comment: show your layout code

Comment: Are you trying to comment on Android Studio? If so, then this is not the right place for that. Otherwise, please add the question along with the code.

Comment: can you also, post the real size of the "image"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar question has been answered here: [why is wrap content bigger than real pixel size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027866/why-is-wrap-content-bigger-than-real-pixel-size)

I am pasting the answer to save time:

A very nice explaintaion for supporting the multiple screens is given at

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

you need to put images in respective folders after scaling.

e.g. if you want 100*100 image then place

75*75 in drawable-ldpi for Low density devices

100*100 in drawable-mdpi for Medium density devices

150*150 in drawable-hdpi for High density devices

200*200 in drawable-xhdpi for Extra High density devices

Comment: I did not think about it, it really started to happen when I put the pictures in the folder drawable ... Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Actually,  `wrap_content` always utilize maximum available size, so sometimes it can stretch the image & sometimes it can reduce the size of the image. To use exact image size, you should put `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in the `ImageView` tag in the manifest.